# Case-Evaluating First Condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

Have a small doubt with the case statement. I am trying to find DateDiff between two dates and i found for one record i am getting the Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate)=0.Instead of showing Green its showing Red.Its evaluating the first case statement.How to obtain Red color for my below statement?Please help

```
 Case     
 When A.key =1 then
 Case     
 when  Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate) <90 then 'Red'
  when  Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate) <0 and  Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate) >=-89   then 'yellow'
 when  Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate) >=0 then 'Green'
 when Datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate) is null then 'Grey' 
 else 'Blue'
 end
  else
 ...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's satisfying the condition you have set for the first `WHEN` because 0 is less than 90.

You need to arrange your conditions to make them mutually exclusive, for example:

```
CASE  
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) IS NULL THEN 'GREY' 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) >= -89 AND DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) < 0 THEN 'YELLOW'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) < 90 THEN 'RED'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate) >= 90 THEN 'GREEN'
END
```

Note, the way you had it setup, your `ELSE` would never be met (i.e. `Blue`) because all possible values are covered by the other `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: So is there any way i can make my Case SQL Statement to evaluate all conditions before showing the results?